# Fill vector until a given condition in another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector `x`:

```
x <- c(0, -0.084, 0.19, 0.23, 0.23, 0.21, 0.04, -0.04, -0.14, -0.29, -0.2, -0.08, 0.16, 0.7, 0.2, -0.15, -0.3)
#                                                               ^
#                                                               ^ 
#                                                         first x < -0.2
```

I want to create a vector `y`, of the same length as `x`, that will be 1 until and including the index of a certain condition in `x`, e.g. when `x` first becomes *less than -0.2*. After that index, `y` should be 0 until the end of the vector:

```
y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
#                                ^
#                 last 1 corresponds to -0.29 in x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which`. By taking the `min` of which, we'll find the first instance of `x < -0.2`

```
newx <- rep(1, length(x))
newx[(min(which(x < -0.2)) + 1):length(x)] <- 0

# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Also `which.max(x < -0.2)` as alternative to `min(which(x < -0.2))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cumprod(c(TRUE, head(x > -0.2, -1)))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
y <- abs(-1 + cumsum(x == -0.2))
y
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the index at which the value first goes below -.2 using which, and then index into your vector and replace everything before that value with 1 and everything after with 0:

```
x <- c(0, -0.084, 0.19, 0.23, 0.23, 0.21, 0.04, -0.04, -0.14, -0.29, -0.2, -0.08, 0.16, 0.7, 0.2, -0.15, -0.3)
idx <- which(x < -.2)[1]
x[1:idx] <- 1; x[(idx+1):length(x)] <- 0
```

Which gets result:

```
> x
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cummin` and `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
cummin(lag(x >= -0.2, default = TRUE))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or with `findInterval`

```
cummin(c(1, findInterval(x, -0.2)[-length(x)]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or using `which.max`

```
+(seq_along(x) <= which.max(x < -0.2))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x= c(0, -0.084, 0.19, 0.23, 0.23, 0.21, 0.04, -0.04, -0.14, -0.29, -0.2, -0.08, 0.16, 0.7, 0.2, -0.15, -0.3))
df[1:which(x<=-0.2)[1], y:=1]
df[is.na(y), y:=0]
df
#Output 
         x y
 1:  0.000 1
 2: -0.084 1
 3:  0.190 1
 4:  0.230 1
 5:  0.230 1
 6:  0.210 1
 7:  0.040 1
 8: -0.040 1
 9: -0.140 1
10: -0.290 1
11: -0.200 0
12: -0.080 0
13:  0.160 0
14:  0.700 0
15:  0.200 0
16: -0.150 0
17: -0.300 0
```